# How to add variable to value of click button

Tags: jquery

I am creating Comment Box using below code.I want to create comment box for comment but unable to assign variable value to click button.

How can I assign `id="cmnt'+i+'"` to value of `$("#bn")` in below code

```js
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {    
            var i = 0;

            $("#cmnt").keypress(function(e) {

                var key = e.which;    
                i++;    
                if (key == 13) {    
                    var data = $(this).val();
                        $("#box").append(    
                        $('<div>' + data + '</div>' + '<a href="#" id="cmnt' + i + '" >Comment</a>' + '<div id="ct' + i + '"></div>')    
                    );    
                }

                $("#bn").on("click", function() {

                    $(".ct").append(    
                        $('<input type="text" id="scmnt' + i + '" />' + '<div id="scs' + i + '"></div>')    
                    );

                    $(".scmnt").keypress(function(e) {

                        var key = e.which;

                        if (key == 13) {

                            var $vv = $(this).val();    
                            $(".scs").append('<div>' + $vv + '</div>');    
                        }

                    });

                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="cmnt" />
    <div id="box">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It changes the ID attribute to 'cmnt' + i.

```
$('#bn').attr('id', 'cmnt'+i);
```

Comment: please add a brief explanation as to how your solution resolves the OPs problem. please review [answer]

Comment: No..can you please post full code along with your solution